# How to set the text size of a LabelView in SproutCore

Tags: layout, sproutcore, sproutcore-views

This may be obvious, but I can't find how to enlarge the font size of an `SC.LabelView`. What I have now is

```
title: SC.LabelView.design({
    layout: { centerX: 0, centerY: 0, height: 36, width: 200 },
    tagName: "h1",
    value: "Contacts"
})
```

Although it is an `h1`, it stays 'normal' text, but it is a title, as suggested by the property name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SproutCore includes a CSS reset so that you can style your page and make it look the same across all browsers.

The best way to edit your styles is to add some CSS to `my_app/resources/main_page.css` using the `font-size` property.

```
$theme h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

There are some comments and links to additional resources in the `main_page.css` file, but you can learn more from the [Chance guide](http://guides.sproutcore.com/chance.html).

Comment: Note that along with tagName, you can also specify the classNames property, which takes an array of classes which you can use to further style your view. (Since tag names are prevented from impacting style, for the (very good) reason that Topher mentioned, and applications have less need for semantical markup than documents do, SC apps usually end up making pretty sparse use of tagName. No reason to avoid it though.) Useful for getting fancy: [classNameBindings](http://blog.sproutcore.com/classnamebindings-easy-dynamic-css/).

Comment: Ah, I completely forgot about CSS, focusing on an SC-only solution.

Comment: Bingo. It's important to remember that SC wants you to use CSS for everything style-related (with the exception of layout). It's just slow HTML that it wants you to stay away from!